# import requests giving "Traceback (most recent call last):", Issue with python version or environment?

Tags: python, request, environment-variables, python-import

during my slow coding progress, I just found out that probably I have some issue with environment variables and I am little bit confused with it. I am using python 3.6 in Pycharm tool and it seems, that I have both versions of python installed:

```
Controller$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.17
Controller$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.5
```

When I running my script via console I got expected results, but when I put it in the /var/www/html (into localhost), I've got only the error message saying: "Traceback (most recent call last): ". After that PHP spit some bunch of error messages regarding importings:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/doozie/Pycharm
> Projects/Python Learning/JA GAME/log2.py", line 5, in import requests
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/**init**.py", line 43,
> in import urllib3 File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/**init**.py", line 8, in from
> .connectionpool import ( File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29,
> in from .connection import ( File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 40, in
> from .util.ssl_ import ( File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/**init**.py", line 3, in
> from .connection import is_connection_dropped File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 3,
> in from .wait import wait_for_read File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/wait.py", line 1, in from
> .selectors import ( File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/selectors.py", line 14,
> in from collections.abc import namedtuple, MappingImportError: cannot
> import name 'namedtuple'

What I found out is, that when I commented the "import request", the message is printed with no issue. So I was digging little bit and found that it is most probably due the python version which might be installed in wrong environment ?

I tried to run some commands, pip upgrade, pip install requests, but even after that, I got: "Requirement already satisfied" or other error messages, I dont understand:

```
Controller$ sudo pip3 install requests
[sudo] password for doozie:         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping
```

So I decided to write and ask here before I run some commands which might completely destroy whole python or my progress, or even better my whole system :D.

Can you please advise me how can I correct this ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the solution via this reddit link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/tzja94/comment/i4022j7/
As I had a similar symptoms as in the case guy had, I went through the path from the error and did these changes in the "selectors.py" file.

```
# from collections.abc import namedtuple, Mapping
from collections import namedtuple
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

I simply commented the line: "from collections.abc import namedtuple, Mapping"
and added two new lines. "from collections import namedtuple" and "from collections.abc import Mapping".

After that import requests start working without error.

Many thanks all.